# 'numpy.int64' object has no attribute 'loc'

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a csv file with date and two input values. Here I need to read date with value contain in first column. here I used the code and it gave me this error"'numpy.int64' object has no attribute 'loc'"

Here is my code:

```
data = pd.read_csv("data6.csv")

data['date']= pd.to_datetime(data['date'] + " " + data['time'].str.strip(), format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')

filtered = data['X']
current_X = filtered.iloc[0]
current_time = filtered.iloc[0].loc['date']
```

error:

```html
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-b3a8e880770f> in <module>()
      1 filtered = data['x']
      2 current_x = filtered.iloc[0]
----> 3 current_time = filtered.iloc[0].loc['date']

AttributeError: 'numpy.int64' object has no attribute 'loc'
```

my csv file :

```html
date       time  x   x1
8/6/2018 6:15:00  141      0
8/6/2018 6:45:00  0      20
8/6/2018 7:45:00  0          0
8/6/2018 9:00:00  0      0
8/6/2018 9:25:00  95      30
8/6/2018 9:30:00  0      0
8/6/2018 11:00:00 149      0
8/6/2018 11:30:00 0      0
8/6/2018 13:30:00 0      40
8/6/2018 13:50:00 85      0
8/6/2018 15:00:00 0      0
8/6/2018 15:25:00 0      0
```

Comment: `filtered` is Series, contains only `X` column data. And you are trying to get `date`, which doesn't exists in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 possible solutions - select by positions with [`Index.get_loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_loc.html) for position of `date` column with [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
current_time = data.iloc[0, data.columns.get_loc('date')]
```

Or get label of first index value and select by [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
current_time = data.loc[data.index[0], 'date']
```

If there is default RangeIndex:

```
current_time = data.loc[0, 'date']
```

Your solution not working, because:

```
#returned Series
filtered = data['X']
#returned first value of Series - scalar
current_X = filtered.iloc[0]
#error
current_time = filtered.iloc[0].loc['date']
```

Comment: Is it tested? Please look at my comment under question.

Comment: @shaikmoeed  - oops, you are right, need `data` instead `filtered`

Comment: @jezrael I think your answer is correct. But I have a doubt , if I want to read the date of second column input value, then how to read it?

Comment: @jezrael ya I got it. Thank you very much